# Объект js в массив

Tags: javascript

У меня есть объект вида

```
[
    {
       year: '1982'
    },
    {
       month: 'June'
    },
    {
       day: 13
    },
]
```

Мне надо его переделать в массив и что бы я мог обращаться к элементам массива по ключу (year, month и т.д)
Все перепробовал но никак не сделаю. Подскажите пожалуйста

[image: Вот такой объект]

Comment: потому что наоборот - в объект

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы перепутали объект и массив

```js
console.log([
    {
       year: '1982'
    },
    {
       month: 'June'
    },
    {
       day: 13
    },
].reduce((res, el) => Object.assign(res, el), {}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
let obj = {
 year: 1982,
 month: 'June',
 day: 13
}
```

Comment: Я получаю объект с API